# kohana 2 return empty page in browser only

Tags: kohana

My app is built on Kohana 2,at first I built it in windows with php5.4, it worked well,  now I move it to fedora I use php 5.5.9 and it always return empty page in browser, but if I run it in command line, it works  well.
I noticed that in bootstrap file after the line require Kohana,it return empty page, before this line I can print something in browser
there's no error in serve logs. can anyone  help me. I tried many ways but it still return empty page

Comment: You need to check your logs.

Comment: no error in log. the problems is with php 5.5.9 if php version <=5.4 it works ok

Answer (score 0):

There are many things changed in php 5.4 >=, and probably many kohana lib files causing an issue, one possible thing is mysql connection type because mysql is replace by mysqli/pdo.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation